# How to pass list parameters for each object using Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, url, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC `RequestMapping` here for `GET` parameters. Below is my code -

```
@RequestMapping(value = "index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public HashMap<String, String> handleRequest(@RequestParam("dc1Servers") String dc1Servers, @RequestParam("dc2Servers") String dc2Servers, @RequestParam("dc3Servers") String dc3Servers) {
    HashMap<String, String> model = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String helloWorld = "Hello World!";
    model.put("greeting", helloWorld);

    System.out.println(dc1Servers);
    System.out.println(dc2Servers);
    System.out.println(dc3Servers);

    return model;
}
```

I am hitting this URL - `http://127.0.0.1:8080/dataweb/index?dc1Servers=3&dc2Servers=3&dc3Servers=3` then it goes into the above code and prints out `3` on the console for all the print and works fine.

Now if you see, I have `dc1`, `dc2` and `dc3`.

So for `dc1`, I would like to send these in the URL as the parameters-

```
dc1Servers=3

dc1HostA
dc1HostB
dc1HostC

dc1IPAddresssA
dc1IPAddresssB
dc1IPAddresssC
```

Similarly for `dc2`, I would like to send these in the URL as the parameters-

```
dc2Servers=3

dc2HostA
dc2HostB
dc2HostC

dc2IPAddresssA
dc2IPAddresssB
dc2IPAddresssC
```

Similarly for `dc3`, I would like to send these in the URL as the parameters-

```
dc3Servers=3

dc3HostA
dc3HostB
dc3HostC

dc3IPAddresssA
dc3IPAddresssB
dc3IPAddresssC
```

Now I am not sure how would I construct an URL for this use case and how would my method will look like? I would like to send them in one single URL call.

Is this use case possible to do using Spring MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the parameters any way you see fit, one way is to pass them by their natural grouping like this: `http://127.0.0.1:8080/dataweb/index?dc1Server=dc1HostA,dc1IPAddressA&dc1Server=dcHostB,dc1IPAddressB....`

By using the same parameter name for each group you'd need to use a `MultiValueMap`. A `MultiValueMap` is more or less a `Map<String, List<String>>`, so parameters with the same name(dc1Server, dc2Server, etc) would be in the same list. You would use this to get a full list of the params you passed in like this:

```
public HashMap<String, String> handleRequest(@RequestParam MultiValueMap<String,String> allRequestParams)
```

Then you'd have 3 keys, `dc1Server` would contain all the dc1Server data, `dc2Server` all the 
dc2Server etc

Could look into using `@ModelAttribute` if you want to do direct mapping to domain objects: [Link](http://java.dzone.com/articles/using-spring-mvc%E2%80%99s)

**EDIT**

```
public void testSpringMultiValueMap() {
        MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
        map.add("dc1Server", "dc1HostA,dc1IPAddressA");
        map.add("dc1Server", "dc1HostB,dc1IPAddressB");
        map.add("dc1Server", "dc1HostC,dc1IPAddressC");
        map.add("dc2Server", "dc2HostA,dc2IPAddressA");
        map.add("dc2Server", "dc2HostB,dc2IPAddressB");
        map.add("dc2Server", "dc2HostC,dc2IPAddressC");

        List<String> dc1List = map.get("dc1Server");

        for(String pair: dc1List) {
            String[] tokens = pair.split(",");
            System.out.println("host: " + tokens[0] + " ip: " + tokens[1]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks MagicMan for the suggestion.. This makes sense to me.. One question I have is, how would I iterate this MultiValueMap to extract fields from it? Can you provide an example on my use case for this as well?

Comment: And here `MultiValueMap` is from import `org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap;` ? Correct

Comment: Yes, it's the Spring `MultiValueMap`. A good example of how it works can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15182886/772385

Comment: Thanks.. But in my case as it is a Map of String and List<String> but somehow it is not getting iterated if I am doing it this way...

Comment: When you call `get("dc1Server")` it should give back a `List<String>` object for that key. Each one should look like `dc1HostA,dc1IPAddress`, you an call `split(",")` to break them apart if you need to

Comment: do I need to split `dc1HostA,dc1IPAddress` on `,` for this? I cannot iterate this list? This is what not happening currently..

Comment: Check the edit I just added, it should give you an idea how to interate the `MultiValueMap` and properly split it up

Answer (score 0):

Url parameters are strings, so your options for passing a variable number of strings are:

### Encode your values in a single url parameter

The simplest way is to use delimiter characters if you know your values will never contain them. Given you're trying to pass ip addresses and host names, this should work for you: `&dc1Servers=dc1HostA,dc1IPAddressA,dc1HostB,dc1IPAddressB`, etc.

### Pass the same url parameter multiple times

Put the `@RequestParam` annotation on a method arg of type `String[]`, and pass that url parameter multiple times: `&dc1Host=dc1HostA&dc1IPAddress=dc1IPAddressA&dc1Host=dc1HostB&dc1IPAddress=dc1IPAddressB`, etc.

Here are some more details on this approach: [How to pass post array parameter in Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399347/how-to-pass-post-array-parameter-in-spring-mvc)